# Can't use Sequelize.Op.Not as intended on Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have the following code:

```
async getMentorSchedule(mentorId) {
    try{
        var schedule = await MentorSchedule.findAll({
            where: { 
                personId: mentorId,
                id: {
                    [Sequelize.Op.not]: Sequelize.col('mentoring.mentor_schedule_id')
                }
            },
            include: [
                { 
                    model: Mentoring,
                }
            ],
        })

        return {
            status: 200,
            message: 'Agenda carregada com sucesso',
            content: schedule
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
        return {
            status: 500,
            message: error.message,
            content: []
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get all MentorSchedule rows which id isn't in Mentoring table as a Foreign Key. The following code doesn't returns any rows, just a empty list. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i've achieved to make it work. The following code:

```
    async getMentorSchedule(mentorId) {
    try{
        var schedule = await MentorSchedule.findAll({
            where: [
                Sequelize.where(Sequelize.col('mentor_schedule.person_id'), mentorId),
                Sequelize.where(Sequelize.col('mentoring.id'), null), 
            ],
            include: [
                { 
                    model: Mentoring,
                    required: false,
                }
            ],
        })

        return {
            status: 200,
            message: 'Agenda carregada com sucesso',
            content: schedule
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
        return {
            status: 500,
            message: error.message,
            content: []
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, it searchs for null entries on relationship (this.hasOne(models.Mentoring)) in MentorSchedule. So, it returns all MentorSchedule rows which id isn't in Mentoring table as a Foreign Key.